# Is it possible to get Yahoo pipes to return slightly older (possibly cached) data if the source website is down?

Tags: caching, http-status-codes, yahoo-pipes

I'm using yahoo pipes to get data from a website, but I've found that when that website is down, pipes returns an empty data (items) array.  Is it possible to get pipes to check the website status and return an older version of the data if it gets a status other than 200?  So, for example, if the website went down at 2pm, pipes would return me the older data from 1pm.

Comment: I don't think Yahoo Pipes has such functionality. You'd have to create your own.

Answer (score 0):

Pipes does have some internal caching, so if you repeatedly refresh the same pipe you'll get the same output data for a while. However as @janos also mentioned, there is no caching beyond that. You may get valid data for a short time but then it will go away (if the source goes away).